# Need help with back-reference matching on regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have been working on this regex:
`{link=([^|{}]+)\||([^|{}]+)\||([^|{}]+)}`

I wish to capture any non-pipe or bracket chars and place them in appropriate backreference (group).

How can I return the following:

1. If test string is `{link=a}` return `a` into group 3.
2. If test string is `{link=a|b}` return `a` into group 2, `b` into group 3.
3. If test string is `{link=a|b|c}` return `a` into group 1, `b` into group 2, `c` into group 3.

Having issues where the strings are not correctly being picked up into correct groups on all permutations with the above regex.  I think I have bracket grouping issues and/or `OR` (`|`) statement issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python, but the syntax should be the same,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
ptn = re.compile(r"""
    {link=
    (?:
      (?:([^|}]+)\|)?
      (?:([^|}]+)\|)
    )?
    ([^|}]+)
    }
    """, re.VERBOSE)

l = [
    "{link=a}",
    "{link=a|b}",
    "{link=a|b|c}",
    "{link=a} {link=a|b} {link=a|b|c}",
]
for s in l:
    for m in ptn.finditer(s):
        print "%s => matchs: %s => m.group(3): %s" % (
                s, m.group(0), m.group(3))
```

and result:

```
{link=a} => matchs: {link=a} => m.group(3): a
{link=a|b} => matchs: {link=a|b} => m.group(3): b
{link=a|b|c} => matchs: {link=a|b|c} => m.group(3): c
{link=a} {link=a|b} {link=a|b|c} => matchs: {link=a} => m.group(3): a
{link=a} {link=a|b} {link=a|b|c} => matchs: {link=a|b} => m.group(3): b
{link=a} {link=a|b} {link=a|b|c} => matchs: {link=a|b|c} => m.group(3): c
```

Comment: I took the liberty to fix that (cosmetic), but more importantly to exclude the pipe from the first captures.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Dyno, can you try and run this again with l = ["{link=a} {link=a|b} {link=a|b|c}"].  I think you will find we run into issues, blocks start to merge into the one group etc.  I am using this for a custom-syntax -> hyperlink tag generator and it's a valid use-case I might have many links in the one string that my regex will be tested upon.

Comment: modified upon request, is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks that works great.  I can see each capture set within group 1, 2, 3 perfectly now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

How about capturing all the matches in the same group?

```
string[] tests = {
    "{link=a}",
    "{link=a|b}",
    "{link=a|b|c}",
};

var link = @"(?<link>[^|]+)";
var pattern = new Regex(String.Format(@"^\{{link={0}(\|{0})*\}}$", link));

foreach (var s in tests) {
    Match m = pattern.Match(s);

    if (!m.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: FAIL", s);
        continue;
    }

    Console.Write("{0}: PASS ", s);
    foreach (var l in m.Groups["link"].Captures)
        Console.Write("[{0}]", l);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
{link=a}: PASS [a]
{link=a|b}: PASS [a][b]
{link=a|b|c}: PASS [a][b][c]
```